# Account deleted for being a sock puppet, accounts merged

Tags: support, merge-accounts

Today my account was suspended in SO for voting irregularities. I admit, I was abusing (though not necessarily for the rep points) and I deserve the suspension. However, I have a question. The "sock puppet" account was not actually intended to be as such, I started it so I could ask really "dumb" questions without making [the real] me look foolish. Some I found the answers for on my own and have answered them using my real account (Is this ok?). I have also honestly answered other questions for other users.

I have earned a bit of legitimate reputation points on the "puppet" account. It seems as if the two accounts have been merged (Answers posted under "puppet" account are now shown as answered by my real account).

My question is do I get the rep earned from the "puppet" account by legit methods merged into my normal account? For example:

```
Real account
Total rep: 5000
False rep: 2500

Puppet account
Total rep: 2000
False rep: 1000
```

Would merging the accounts result in the real account having 2500 (legit rep for real account only) or 3500 (sum of legit rep for both accounts).

Comment: `Some I found the answers for on my own and have answered them using my real account (Is this ok?).` - that is *not* ok, and was probably why you were found out and merged in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, if two weeks is "a while" then a 7 days suspension must indeed feel excessive.

Comment: Considering you had a fake conversation with yourself in the comments of your most recent question, I call BS on finding the answers legitimately and posting them with your other account. 7 days is way too short.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the accounts have been merged, the reputation of the two is essentially combined - however, even after removing self-voting (which is of course not allowed), this *might* be slightly lower, as the daily rep-cap still applies - i.e. if each account got 15 upvotes in a day (from other users), that would previously have shown as 150 on each (300), but will now be 200.

The rep is automatically recalculated when coming out of suspension.

I've checked the logs, and indeed there was a merge:

> moderator merge users id = 591001 into id = 302908

Your *effective* reputation (ignoring the suspension) is currently 4010

Comment: @DustinDavis that would be a question for who-ever applied the suspension

Comment: @DustinDavis: Reducing with what argument/reason? It's a punishment...and as it seems, it's working the right way.